# Cannot get property 'location' on null object compare wsdl

Tags: wsdl

I'm trying to compare two WSDL files, but the error described in the title of the question occurs, my code is presented below.
WSDLParser parser = new WSDLParser();

```
    InputStream stream = BackendImplService.class.getResourceAsStream(wsdlPath);
    HttpConnecter httpConnecter = new HttpConnecter();
    byte[] res = httpConnecter.getByteArrResponse(new HttpGet(new URI(Properties.getWsdlPath()+"?wsdl")));
    InputStream stream2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(res);

    Definitions wsdl1 = parser.parse(stream);

    // Definitions wsdl2 = parser.parse(stream);
    Definitions wsdl2 = parser.parse(stream2);

    WsdlDiffGenerator diffGen = new WsdlDiffGenerator(wsdl1, wsdl2);
    List<Difference> lst = diffGen.compare();
```

I read a bunch of material about WSDL, but I couldn’t find anything clear, please help!